# Prisma: argument missing but I'm sure I included it

Tags: next.js, prisma

I'm encountering an internal server error while attempting to perform a POST request to an endpoint at api/v1 using Next.js App Router with Prisma. The error message indicates that the `slug` argument is missing despite being included.

Below is the pertinent code from app/page.tsx handling the request:

```js
const [showPageModal, setShowPageModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [showSuccessModal, setShowSuccessModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [slug, setSlug] = useState<string>(generateDocumentName())
const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState<string>('')
const [author, setAuthor] = useState<string>('')
const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>('default')
const [pageUrl, setPageUrl] = useState<string>('https://mditor.vercel.app/')

const createPage = async () => {
  console.log(slug)
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/v1', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: pageTitle,
        author: author,
        content: documents[currentDocumentIndex]?.content || '',
        theme: theme,  
        slug: slug,
      })
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      // ...
    } else {
      alert('Owch, something wen\'t wrong')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating page:', error);
    alert('Owch, something went wrong' + error)
  }
};
```

Additionally, here's the code from app/api/v1/route.ts, which represents the API endpoint:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(req, res) {
  // Create a new page
  const { title, author, content, theme, slug} = req.body;
  try {
    const newPage = await prisma.page.create({
      data: {
        title: title,
        author: author,
        content: content,
        theme: theme,
        slug: slug
      }
    });
    res.status(200).json(newPage);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating page:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

Moreover, the schema.prisma file is as follows:

```
// prisma/schema.prisma

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Page {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title    String
  author   String
  content  String
  theme    String
  slug     String
}
```

I've also verified the request body in the networks tab of the developer tools, confirming that `slug` is not null. Despite this, the issue persists. Any insights into what might be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.